# Where does Magento take the time from?

Tags: timezone

I upgraded my Cloud hosting account (doubled the processor and memory)  but then was getting a problem with the Session Cookie Management (after customers would log in - it would take them to a page which says: You have no items in your shopping cart. I figured out this is a Session Cookie problem (the end users computer time runs ahead of server’s time, cookies will not get set for Magento frontend as well as backend. For example, end user’s computer time is 1 hour forward than server’s time, that means the cookie (holding user’s session id) will expire as soon as user logs in or tries to add an item).

I contacted the hosting company to correct the server time and they replied:

> Could you please let us know where is the application taking the time
>   from? Since all applications can be set to use a specific time, we
>   would like to be sure that changing the server time will affect the
>   application as well.

in my Magento backend - I have Mountain Standard Time set in:

```
System - Configuration - General - General - Locale Options
```

The hosting now says this:

We will gladly change the server time zone for you, but please note that this is a server wide change, that will affect all accounts on the server, and also that we do not know which time zone your Magento installation should use.

Please let us know which time zone should we set, and we will proceed with the change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at http://inchoo.net/magento/guide-through-magentos-timezones/

Comment: Thank you for trying to help R.S. - I looked at that page but I'm not sure if I understand it.... in my Magento backend - I have Mountain Standard Time set in:

System - Configuration - General - General - Locale Options

The hosting now says this:

We will gladly change the server time zone for you, but please note that this is a server wide change, that will affect all accounts on the server, and also that we do not know which time zone your Magento installation should use.

Please let us know which time zone should we set, and we will proceed with the change.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621447/time-in-magento and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12508/what-timezone-are-magento-cron-jobs-being-run-in and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5938/how-to-overcome-timezone-problem-in-magento

Comment: Cookies are always set by GMT, so time zone is irrelevant. Only the accuracy of the server's time and the client's time matters, not the time zone.